# React-admin non-persistent redux state

Tags: redux, react-redux, react-admin, redux-persist

I am using an some filters and actions in a react-admin project.

A react-admin custom Action makes changes in the UI by changing redux state.
However by reloading the page the part of redux state changed by react-admin Action is not preserved.

Which is the best practice to have a **persistent redux state** while preserving **compatibility with react-admin**?

Comment: Can you share your code? You need to pass customReducers props with your reducers to the Admin component

Answer (score 0):

Even though I have not tweaked redux in a custom way while using react-admin, I think what you need is using custom-sagas as described in the official react-admin  [documentation](https://marmelab.com/react-admin/Admin.html#customsagas).
Take a look at [this](https://engineering.invisionapp.com/post/persist-redux-state-by-using-sagas/) as well, might be of help.
Good luck!